# Search consecutive schedule in Notepad++ using RegEx multiline

Tags: regex, notepad++

My requirement is to search on Notepad++, sample text shown below:

```
UM001 Uddharana Madhava

Date: 3/6/2021, Thursday
Topic: Bangla Economics
Language: Bengali

Date: 4/6/2021, Friday
Topic: Bangla Economics
Language: Bengali

Date: 3/6/2021, Thursday
Topic: Bangla Economics
Language: English

CJ009 Cidananda Janardana

Date: 3/6/2021, Thursday
Topic: Bangla Economics
Language: Telugu
```

The search result should highlight

```
UM001 Uddharana Madhava

Date: 3/6/2021, Thursday
Topic: Bangla Economics
Language: Bengali

Date: 4/6/2021, Friday
Topic: Bangla Economics
Language: Bengali
```

It should not highlight from other teachers schedule

```
Date: 3/6/2021, Thursday
Topic: Bangla Economics
Language: English

CJ009 Cidananda Janardana

Date: 3/6/2021, Thursday
Topic: Bangla Economics
Language: Telugu
```

```
Language(.+?)Date
```

The above search pattern is not working so I tried

```
Language(.+?)(?![A-Z][A-Z]\d{3})Date
Language(.+?)(?![A-Z][A-Z]\d{3})(.+?)Date
```

These two are also not working.
Please suggest how can I achieve the desired result.
Here is what I am looking for, if there is a name in between Language and date, that should not be captured.
[Here is a link of image which shows my requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QT1v.jpg)

Comment: What exactly do you want to find here?

Comment: Are you looking for this: `^Language:.*$\s*\nDate`  ?

Comment: `^Language:.+\R\RDate:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To highlight only parts with multiple Date parts:

```
^[A-Z][A-Z]\d{3}\b\h+\S.*\s*(?>\RDate:\h.*(?:\R(?!Date:|[A-Z][A-Z]\d{3}\b).*)*){2,}
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z][A-Z]\d{3}\b` Match the format of the values `UM001` for example
- `\h+\S.*\s*` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars, at least a single non whitespace char and the rest of the line. Then match optional whitespace chars, that could also match a newline
- `(?>` Atomic group

  - `\RDate:\h.*` Match a newline, `Date:`  and the rest of the line
  - `(?:\R(?!Date:|[A-Z][A-Z]\d{3}\b).*)*` Match all lines that do not start with either `Date:` or a pattern like the start value
- `){2,}` Close the group and repeat 2 or more times

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IrTFDQ/1/).

Comment: This is really promising, somehow not working on Notepad++.

Comment: @HiM It works on my Notepad++ V7.9.1 See for example the replacement here https://imgur.com/a/xNQ9v3D

Comment: Interesting, my Notepad++ is v8.1.5, it should work in that case. But it throws me the error "Can't find the text...". My search mode is Regex. But your code is too good, though I need some time to grasp it. I will make it work. :)

Comment: @HiM I copied the text from the question, maybe there are spaces at the start of the string or before the Date parts. Try it with optional leading spaces https://regex101.com/r/LiN9fW/1

Answer (score 1):

Your answer isn't clear what you want to highlight  , but I guess you wanted this ...
Find: `^Language: Bengali\n+Date:`

See the attachment
[image]

Or

Find: `^Language: Bengali\n*Date.*`

Your desired result will look like this ,

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to understand my requirement and providing a solution. 

But what I am looking for is, the first seach should select Language to Date in line 5,6,7 (in your first image) and find next should select line 9,10,11 but next find should not select text in line number 13 to 17.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Both attachments were updated ,,, Note the `\n+` will highlight empty lines as many as possible located between language and date....

Comment: This helped me to construct the search expression so it highlights whatever be the language. Here is my code: ^Language: \w+\n+Date:

Comment: Of course this `\w+` will highlight any words and digits, but you should to write Bengali literally to help engine recognize your pattern „ use my first example,  avoid your regex